# Как они делают такие рекламные штуки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

господа!

Может кто-то знает как они делают открытие отдельного окна на такой, непохожей на гугл хром, вкладке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращаю Ваше внимание, что это открылось само собой, при клике по ссылке на одном из сайтов в браузере гугл хром, а также на то что оно совершенно не выглядит как гугл хром

Comment: [window.open](https://learn.javascript.ru/popup-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно как-то так это делают:
Пробовать этот код необходимо на своей html странице. На сайте stackoverflow окно не откроется так как будет заблокировано.

```js
function openNewWindow(){
    let params = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no, width=0,height=0,left=-1000,top=-1000`;
    window.open('https://javascript.info', 'example', params);
}

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', openNewWindow);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Open</button>
```